# Static website with different locations in dokku

Tags: docker, nginx, dokku

I am using **dokku** and docker to run my static website. I want to create some subdirectories and locaions using `nginx.conf` file. This is structure of my files

```
└── first
    ├── dist
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── page.html
    │   ├── ...
    ├── tools

└── second
    ├── dist
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── page.html
    │   ├── ...
    ├── tools
```

And I want my site to be like `example.com/first` to load `index.html` in `dist` folder of `first` and `example.com/second` to load `index.html` in `dist` folder of `second`.

So I created a `nginx.conf` like this:

```
location /first {
  alias /app/first/dist;
}

location /second {
  alias /app/second/dist;
}
```

But I get 403 error for trying to get pages and when I go to `example.com/first/dist` everything is fine for first website. How can I config my `nginx.conf` file?